# Loading a 2d map in chunks

Tags: java, 2d

Hello I'm working on a game that loads its world in chunks.
I had a idea how to do this but I'm not sure if I should do it like this.

I tought about to not have a array of Chunks and try for each AABB with the visible area. I think it would be faster to only check AABB for the chunks near the visible Area.

Whit 2 arrays:

- preLoaded (Yellow) These chunks only have basic informations like x, y, indexX, indeyY and check each screen change for AABB collision.
- loaded (Green) These chunks have information about the terrain and will be rendered.

[image: chunk1]][image: chunk2]

Picture 1:

- Red rectangle = visible area
- Green Area = loaded chunks
- Yellow Area = check for intersecting with visible area

Picture 2:

- red area

  - dark = unload chunk
  - light = free chunk to the pool.
- dark green = load chunk;
- light green = obtain chunk

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: If this way would work good or I sould do somthink else.